# Why is the production team making prequels of X-Men rather than sequels?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, movie-franchise

I am a die-hard fan of the X-Men animated series [X-Men Evolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men%3a_Evolution) and I also like the [X-Men Movie Trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_%28film_series%29#Main_series)

In addition to the main trilogy there are two more movies ([X-Men Origins: Wolverine](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0458525/) and [X-Men: First Class](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1270798/)) which are prequels.

Why have the writers and directors decided to do *prequels* rather than a *sequel*?

[**Wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_%28film_series%29#Sequels_to_X-Men%3a_First_Class) says that they are planing for a sequel for the *X-Men First Class* movie but there is no clarification about an *X-Men 4* movie.

Comment: It is just my opinion, but I can't be the only one who is tired of misunderstood teenagers or just teenagers in general being main characters. It is a trend, so superhero-movies are not an exception(i am number four, the amazing spider-man). Hopefully they will stop doing this and return to more interesting characters, not just people at puberty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this quote on the X-men: First Class wiki page gives us a decent amount of insight as to why they're making "prequels":

> As producer Simon Kinberg read the comic series X-Men: First Class, he
>   suggested studio 20th Century Fox to adapt it. Kinberg, however, did
>   not want to follow the comic too much, as he felt "it was not fresh
>   enough in terms of storytelling", considering them too similar to John
>   Hughes movies, and also that the producers wanted an adaptation that
>   would introduce new characters. Both Kinberg and Shuler Donner said
>   they wanted characters with visuals and powers that had not been seen
>   yet, and that worked well as an ensemble even if they did not work
>   together in the comics.[11] Shuler Donner later said the original idea
>   was to green-light First Class depending on the success of X-Men
>   Origins: Magneto

So we see that they wanted a shift in focus from the main set of characters established in the X-Men trilogy.  While quite a few characters were introduced, the main plots revolved around only a hand full of characters.

Another reasoning is that the X-Men universe is quite vast and dynamic.  Each character has more than one story arc that just can't be covered in one or two movies.  For example, if we look at the story arcs for Wolverine, we get something like this:

- Pre-Memory loss (X-Men Origins: Wolverine)
- Post Memory Loss (X-Men Origins: Wolverine 2)
- Wolverine and the X-Men (X-Men 1-3)

Also, character story arcs criss-cross in the X-Men universe.  It is literally a giant bowl of spaghetti, complicated even more by time travel in some instances.

Answer (score 6):

I cannot provide as much insight (or any knowledge about the comics) as DForck42's answer. But from a mere movie viewpoint the finale X-Men tirlogy was a pretty closed end, with many main characters dying, or losing their powers (Xavier, Jean Grey, Magneto).

I guess this can make it a bit harder to start a new story after those events, whereas the time before all those events is still fresh and it might be an easier option to turn there for new X-Men stories (at least for now).

Comment: Ah but it is hinted at that Xavier got a new body and "The Cure" is not as permanent as it seems.

Comment: @TylerShads Oh yes, the final scene (with Magneto moving the chess figure) is indeed a nice hint for potential sequels. But what do you mean with Xavier getting a new body? Where was this hinted?

Comment: @TylerShads what are you talking about? Xavier got a new body?

Comment: At the end of the credits Moria was with a patient that had lost consciousness and Xavier earlier hinted that one could transfer conscious of a dying human to a body without and at the end the patient moves and Moria exlaims "Charles?!"

Comment: @ChristianRau in x men animated series magneto,xavier,mistique losse their life in season three but they made a twist and made them back again through ancient mutant. So the similar thing can also be done in movie too, if they want. Othervise x4 can be as new begining because they have left so many mutants yet.

Comment: @TylerShads i think i need to watch Xman last stand again to see that schene you are talking about

Comment: @TylerShads By coincidence it just aired on TV, but I didn't see this scene. But I read about it on Wikipedia, nice to know Xavier survived, his death always bothered me. Seems I'm paying the toll for getting cut away the end credits on TV.

Comment: @ChristianRau try [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSkn3KYwmtc)

Comment: @TylerShads nice link, cleared your point

Comment: @ChristianRau if there is any userful information in these comments, please incorporate them into your answer.

Answer (score 2):

There have been 4 movies since the original trilogy (X-Men Origins: Wolverine, X-Men: First Class, The Wolverine, and X-Men: Days of Future Past).

The reason Fox decided to make prequels instead of sequels is because of the third X-Men movie (The Last Stand).

Firstly, that movie got terrible reviews and a lot of fans hated it, which made Fox scared that a sequel wouldn't succeed. However, the main reason is because The Last Stand really messed up all chances of a sequel by killing so many important characters.

Professor X died, Cyclops died, Jean Grey died, Magneto lost his powers... How would they make a sequel with only Wolverine, Storm, Rogue and Beast?

However, in the latest X-Men movie Wolverine goes back in time and changes the past so that nothing from The Last Stand ever happened, and everyone's still alive. So the next X-Men movie, X-Men: Apocalypse, will be a sequel and not a prequel.

Comment: Professor X didn't died completely ( refer end credit), Magneto still have powers (chess scene) and Jean Grey returned in comics by some twist which was possible for movies too. And one correction Apocalypse is said to be prequel of X-2, 3 but sequel to first class and days of future past.